Why do three sites (SJ, VY, Norrtåg) offer three different prices for the same train connection?
Looking for a train connection from Stockholm to Kaitum on 5 September 2024, I was surprised to see three different prices depending on where I search.
Via Norrtåg, the connection 06:22 – 19:45 is SEK 867, offering only non-flexible:

Via Vy, it is SEK 1006 for non-flexible or SEK 1374 for flexible (shown at the next page, not in screenshot):

Via SJ, it is SEK 1305, offering only flexible:

Even when comparing tickets with the same (I think?) level of flexibility, that makes SEK 1305 at SJ or SEK 1374 at Vy for fully flexible tickets, or SEK 867 at Norrtåg vs. SEK 1006 at Vy for non-flexible tickets.
What is going on here?  I thought competing ticket booking systems connected to the same backend and should show the same prices, but this is not the case here.  Why are the prices different?
For the connection in question, part of the journey is operated by SJ and another part by Norrtåg in cooperation with Vy, so all companies are directly or indirectly involved.

What you see is very common everywhere throughout Europe and neither special nor surprising. As soon as multiple train operators sell tickets to the same train, particularly when it comes to international trains or as in your case, an itinerary involving multiple train operators, you can be pretty sure that the ticket prices are deviating and that you in some cases can save a lot of money by comparing different sellers.
Your assumption that 'competing ticket booking systems connect to the same backend' is wrong. They might connect to a common booking system to handle seat reservations, but prices are still in most cases determined by the selling operator and not by the reservation management system. In many cases there is not even a common backend for seat reservations, but each selling operator is simply assigned a fixed contingent of seats and make reservations only from these seats without interacting with the other train operators at all.
In particular, the availability and pricing of saver tickets is almost without exception handled by each selling operator individually. Depending on the algorithm each operator uses to provide saver tickets, this might have interesting effects. The two most common approaches to provide saver tickets are probably:

As soon as the train is available for booking, a fixed number of tickets in each price category are made available, e.g. 10 tickets for €30, 20 tickets for €40 and 50 tickets for €50. The cheapest tickets are simply sold first.

The operator uses dynamic pricing based on occupation and demand predictions, in which case there is not a fixed number of tickets in each price category, but the prices are fluctuating based on a current and floating estimation for profit maximization.


If two selling operators use significantly different strategies, it can lead to seemingly strange results. I just recently booked a train ticket from Munich to Vienna for this Sunday and of course checked the prices both from German Railways (DB) as well as from Austrian Railways (ÖBB). DB still had the cheapest 'Super Sparpreis Europa' tickets available and I could book there for €30. ÖBB had obviously estimated the demand for this train completely different and did not sell saver tickets at all, but wanted €115 for a full price flexible ticket. Flexible tickets tend to have the same or at least similar prices from different operators, but in this case, DB sells flexible tickets for €109, so even here, there is a slight difference in the price for flexible tickets sold by DB and ÖBB.
Another cause for larger discrepancies in ticket prices is that some operators might not sell saver tickets at all for a certain connection. A while ago, I booked a train ticket from Linz in Austria to Písek in the Czech Republic and for this connection, ÖBB only offered full price tickets for currently €39. It is not always obvious why a saver ticket is not available, but I can only assume that in this case, the trip included a leg on a Czech local train and that ÖBB is/was not able to sell saver tickets to domestic, Czech trains. Czech Railways on the other hand sold saver tickets for exactly the same connection for roundabout €7.
When it comes to international trains, it is also not unusual that operators in different countries take the local purchasing power into account when determining ticket prices. This can easily be seen when comparing ticket prices for trains between e.g. Germany and Austria (high purchasing power) and Czech Republic, Slovakia or Hungary (countries with a lower purchasing power). Just as an example, for the train from Munich to Budapest tomorrow morning at 7:23, DB still offers saver tickets for €110. ÖBB, also here, only offer full price tickets for €154 and no saver tickets at all. If you however go to the Hungarian Railways, they currently offer tickets for about €80 and you can save almost 30% on the DB price if you buy your ticket in Hungary instead.
The same also applies to plane and ferry tickets. For the first flight tomorrow from Frankfurt to Copenhagen, Lufthansa sells tickets starting at 350€, while SAS (codeshare partner) offers tickets starting at 390€. When it comes to international ferries, even the same operator often offer tickets at significantly different rates in different countries. If you now want to book the Color Line ferry from Kiel to Oslo on Friday (tomorrow is sold out), you are offered tickets starting at 574€ on their German web site, while on the Norwegian web site, tickets start at 410€.

Hm.  Between DB and SBB or between DB and NS International I am used to getting the same prices.

@gerrit For connections to and from Germany, both SBB and NS are just resellers of DB tickets and not having any own pricing schemes. Even for trains operated entirely by SBB, they sell DB tickets. If you try to book from SBB or NS and look at the ticket conditions, you will see that you actually get DB Sparpreis/Flexpreis tickets. With the exception of SBB having their own full price tickets for connections to Germany, where also here, the prices are slightly different.

I see, so there is a difference between reselling tickets for another operator, and selling own tickets for another operator. I'm used to either the former, or selling only for their own (Flixtrain, Snälltåget, MTRX). And I seem to recall that in Great Britain, prices are also the same no matter at which TOC they are sold.

Followup question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/190380/what-train-operators-sell-train-tickets-in-sweden-nationwide?noredirect=1&lq=1

@gerrit in Great Britain (not Northern ireland or Republic of Ireland) all TOC booking websites are frontends to a single booking system run by https://www.raildeliverygroup.com/

Your idea of how systems work is (probably) flawed. To give an example from a completely different area: A few days ago I was looking at theatre tickets and found significant price differences between the sites I was looking at (and the cheapest/most expensive being different from what I expected), and they all offered the same seats, so they had to connect to some common backend to find out which seats weren't sold.
The primary reason for price differences is probably that the different resellers want different margins. The first part of your journey is with an SJ train, so the price you pay at SJ for that part is probably close to what the other sellers have to pay SJ to sell that ticket, but then they need to make some money on selling that ticket so they add their margin.
Your journey has multiple legs served by different operators, making the whole calculation more complicated.
Several factors affect the cooperation between the operators, and their decision on how to set margins:

Agreements between the companies
It can be a requirement in the contract they won with the authorities granting them a subsidy to operate on the route

and probably more.
Consumer laws (and the mentioned factors, and probably other factors) regulate how you're off when one of the connections is delayed/cancelled/... But in general you're better off buying your ticket(s) in one place, have that in mind before you split up the journey and try to find each leg as cheap as possible.

but then they need to make some money on selling that ticket so they add their margin — that doesn't explain that SJ is the most expensive (because they don't offer a non-flexible option).

Many companies sell the same tickets for the same price whether they are the operating company or not, for me it is also very unusual to see such price differences. How they organize it is not made public.
