What train operators sell train tickets in Sweden nationwide?
This useful answer points out that As soon as multiple train operators sell tickets to the same train, (...) in some cases can save a lot of money by comparing different sellers.  Who are those sellers in case of Sweden?  For 3 September Malmö – Stockholm, I am aware of at least three that are different independent sellers for tickets for largely the same trains (not resellers).  An example from Malmö to Stockholm, where the results are somewhat different between the sellers:
SJ

VY

Norrtåg
Norrtåg is a publicly owned company for trains in the four northern counties and not an obvious try for tickets between Malmö and Stockholm, but they appear to sell tickets nationally:

Others?
Are there other companies that sell their own tickets to Swedish trains nationwide?  It seems that Snälltåget, MTRX, Arlanda Express, or Inlandsbanan only sell tickets to their own trains.  Others, such as Tågab, don't seem to sell tickets at all.  Regional operators such as Skånetrafiken, JLT, or X-Trafik seem to cover only their own area, which is what I would expect (but Norrtåg has no such limitation; however, Norrtåg is not exactly analogous to JLT or X-Trafik).  I suspect Omio is just a reseller of SJ-issued tickets.

Apparently also Öresundståg sells tickets, apparently the same ones as Norrtåg.

My take is that some of the train operators (like SJ or Norrtåg) offer ticket sales for areas that they don't traffic themselves, for convenience. So that customers can type in something like Trelleborg to Stockholm without having to worry about which particular train operators that traffic certain parts of the country. And so that they only need to pay for one ticket even though there may be several train swaps along the way.
In my example, SJ won't traffic Trelleborg to Malmö so they'll offer another company Skånetrafiken. But they will traffic Malmö to Stockholm so for that part of the journey they'll only suggest SJ's own trains.
Other train operators apparently don't care about customer convenience, so if you for example want to travel with MTRX, you'll first have to waste your time studying which areas they traffic as of today's date. They do not seem to traffic Stockholm - Malmö for example, for whatever the reason.
Seems like the safest bet to ensure you cover all operators is to use some non-affiliated 3rd party site/app like Omio or ETC Tåg.

"But they will traffic Malmö to Stockholm so for that part of the journey they'll only suggest SJ's own trains." Rubbish; SJ sells Snälltåget tickets Stockholm <-> Malmö as well

@Crazydre Ok because there was a lawsuit against SJ from MTR regarding why SJ wouldn't sell their tickets, which I believe failed.

Well, there are a couple of other companies, such as Rail Nija(https://rail.ninja/nb/sweden-trains) who sell train tickets. I think it is more or less same like plane tickets. And these companies operate not only in Sweden but also serve other Scandinavian markets.
